# Any cure for a nervous bladder?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, urination

We have a female chihuahua/terrier mix, about a year old, and she has a bladder discipline problem. She pees when I hook her up to the lead so she can go outside. She pees when she's excited. She pees when she thinks she's in trouble. She pees when I tell her to come. She sometimes just pees randomly.

It's gotten to the point where I don't really want to interact with her in any way because I don't want to have pee all over the floor.

Comment: Your sex-neutral pronouns make it difficult to suggest any kind of remedy, as male and female dogs have different anatomy, prone to different conditions related to urination. What sex is your dog? How many times a day do you take your dog outside to void? When your dog urinates due to excitement, how much is there?

Comment: @sleddog Sorry, it's a female dog.

Comment: How many times a day is she taken out?

Comment: @sleddog depends on the day. Some days we both work and she's in the crate, in which case I just move the crate so she has to go directly outside when it's opened. The other days when one of us is home she's let out every couple hours, give or take. The real problem to me is the over submissiveness, where if I approach her to put the lead on, even in a friendly manner and gentle tone, she rolls over and pees all over herself. Or when she knows she did something bad.

Comment: @sleddog For example, as a workaround, I've gotten in the habit of letting her run outside without the lead, empty her bladder, and then I approach her carefully to put the lead on (keeping the pee off the deck). She then rolls over as normal, and tries really hard to pee, sometimes getting a couple drops out, but at least I don't have to give her a bath because her bladder is already empty. But the point is that it's not happening because she needs to pee, but she pees because she is too submissive.